# How to restore dashboard controllers and model to fix broken rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-admin, better-errors-gem

This may be a really tough question, but I am fairly new to rails and I am working on my first rails application.

This all happened when failing to create a dashboard feature. Somehow all dashboards controllers and models were deleted and I am working on restoring them. As well, rails_admin has been affected and will no longer work.

I have tried bundle install, rake db:reset db:migrate and still this error appears..

```
ERROR:  relation "dashboards" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"dashboards"'::regclass
```

This is our test for visiting the admin panel at /admin

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Visiting Admin Panel" do
  before do
    @Anag = User.create(first_name: "Anag", middle_initial: "A", last_name: "Avatar", email: "AnagAvatar@example.com", password: "Password", birthday: Date.new(1996), bio: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In vitae tincidunt orci. Quisque mauris
      tortor, dignissim ac dignissim ut, blandit eget risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam mollis augue vestibulum dui facilisis sollicitudin. Nullam sit amet mattis elit. Nulla volutpat elementum enim sed viverra. Cras ante dolor, commodo eu
      velit quis, sagittis egestas erat. Ut ac commodo mauris. Cras quis efficitur ipsum. Fusce fringilla felis ac lectus aliquet, quis dictum sapien posuere. Nunc iaculis lacinia augue, et hendrerit nibh mollis a. Sed sed dolor orci. Sed et turpis dictum, eleifend risus sit
      amet, ultricies eros. Vivamus finibus sapien mauris, a tincidunt nisi eleifend vitae. Maecenas libero sapien, pulvinar et turpis a, malesuada sodales justo.", occupation: "Avatar", motto: "motto motto motto", website_link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar:_The_Last_Airbender",
      hometown: "Air Temple, Western Air Temple",
      confirmed_at: DateTime.new(2017), admin: true)
    nfirmed_at: DateTime.new(2017))
  end

  scenario "with signed in user who's an admin" do
    login_as(@Anag)

    visit "admin"

    expect(current_path).to eq "/admin"

    expect(page).to have_content("Site Administration")

    first(:link, "Assignments").click

    expect(page).to have_content("List of Assignments")
  end
end
```

This is the rspec test results

```
Visiting Admin Panel with signed in user who's an admin
     Failure/Error: visit "admin"

     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "dashboards" does not exist
       LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"dashboards"'::regclass
                                                 ^
       :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                            pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
                    (SELECT c.collname FROM pg_collation c, pg_type t
                      WHERE c.oid = a.attcollation AND t.oid = a.atttypid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation),
                            col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
                       FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                         ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                      WHERE a.attrelid = '"dashboards"'::regclass
                        AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
                      ORDER BY a.attnum
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rails_admin-1.1.0/lib/rails_admin/adapters/active_record.rb:43:in `count'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rails_admin-1.1.0/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/dashboard.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Dashboard>'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rails_admin-1.1.0/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/dashboard.rb:24:in `each'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rails_admin-1.1.0/lib/rails_admin/config/actions/dashboard.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Dashboard>'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rails_admin-1.1.0/app/controllers/rails_admin/main_controller.rb:22:in `instance_eval'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rails_admin-1.1.0/app/controllers/rails_admin/main_controller.rb:22:in `dashboard'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:193:in `public_send'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:193:in `method_missing'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-pjax-1.0.0/lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/remotipart-1.3.1/lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:32:in `call'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/warden-1.2.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:68:in `block in call'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:53:in `each'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:53:in `call'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/mock_session.rb:30:in `request'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/test.rb:244:in `process_request'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/test.rb:58:in `get'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:61:in `process'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:36:in `process_and_follow_redirects'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:22:in `visit'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb:43:in `visit'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:246:in `visit'
     # /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.11.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # ./spec/features/viewing_admin_panel_spec.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ------------------
     # --- Caused by: ---
     # PG::UndefinedTable:
     #   ERROR:  relation "dashboards" does not exist
     #   LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"dashboards"'::regclass
     #                                             ^
     #   /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rails_admin-1.1.0/lib/rails_admin/adapters/active_record.rb:43:in `count'
```

This is our gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Ruby 2.2.4
ruby '2.3.0'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
    gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
    gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

    # Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.4', '>= 3.4.2'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'

  # Added Development gems
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller' # For better_errors advanced features
  gem 'brakeman', require: false # Checking Security
  gem 'guard', '~> 2.14'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 4.7', '>= 4.7.3'
  gem 'guard-cucumber', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.2'
end

group :test do
  # gem 'faker', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.3'
  # gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.1', '>= 3.1.1', require: false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.5'
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.7', '>= 2.7.1'
end

gem 'spring-commands-rspec', :groups => [:development, :test]
gem 'factory_girl_rails', :groups => [:development, :test]

# Added gems
gem 'rails_admin', '~> 1.0'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'slim-rails'

# Authentication
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2.0'

# Authorization
gem 'pundit', '~> 1.1'
gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.4.0'
# Forms
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'country_select'
gem 'mail_form', '~> 1.3.0'
gem 'kaminari', '~> 0.17.0'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.11.2'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.5.1'
gem 'fog-aws'
gem 'unf'
gem 'file_validators' # File Size Validations, May be out of date

# Debudding & Errors
gem 'rubocop', '~> 0.45.0', require: false

# SEO
gem 'meta-tags'
gem 'sitemap_generator'

# Cron jobs
gem 'whenever', require: false

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

This is our server logs output when I visit localhost:3000/admin

```
Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard as HTML
       (2.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."type" IN ('Announcement')
      Announcement Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."type" IN ('Announcement') ORDER BY "posts"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
       (3.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "assignments"
      Assignment Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "assignments".* FROM "assignments" ORDER BY "assignments"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
       (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "categories"
       (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments"
      Comment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" ORDER BY "comments"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
       (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."type" IN ('Coupon')
      Coupon Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."type" IN ('Coupon') ORDER BY "posts"."created_at" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 614ms (ActiveRecord: 42.8ms)


    DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from initialize at /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/better_errors-2.1.1/lib/better_errors/raised_exception.rb:7)
    DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from initialize at /Users/MarcusKA/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/better_errors-2.1.1/lib/better_errors/raised_exception.rb:8)

    PG::UndefinedTable - ERROR:  relation "dashboards" does not exist
    LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"dashboards"'::regclass
                                              ^
    :
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:88:in `block in query'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:566:in `block in log'
      activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:560:in `log'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:87:in `query'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:739:in `column_definitions'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:227:in `columns'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:56:in `columns'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:62:in `columns_hash'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:354:in `load_schema!'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/attributes.rb:233:in `load_schema!'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/attribute_decorators.rb:28:in `load_schema!'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:349:in `load_schema'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:261:in `columns'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:298:in `column_names'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:216:in `aggregate_column'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:239:in `execute_simple_calculation'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:209:in `perform_calculation'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:118:in `calculate'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:40:in `count'
      rails_admin (1.1.0) lib/rails_admin/adapters/active_record.rb:43:in `count'
      rails_admin (1.1.0) lib/rails_admin/config/actions/dashboard.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Dashboard>'
      rails_admin (1.1.0) lib/rails_admin/config/actions/dashboard.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Dashboard>'
      rails_admin (1.1.0) app/controllers/rails_admin/main_controller.rb:22:in `dashboard'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
      activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
      activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
      activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
      activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
      activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
      activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
      activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
      activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
      activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
      actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
      railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
      railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/railtie.rb:193:in `method_missing'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:17:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:46:in `serve'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
      rack-pjax (1.0.0) lib/rack/pjax.rb:12:in `call'
      remotipart (1.3.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:32:in `call'
      warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
      warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
      rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
      rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
      rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
      rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
      rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
      activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
      activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
      activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
      activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
      better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
      better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
      better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
      web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
      web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
      web-console (3.4.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
      railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
      railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
      activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
      activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
      activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
      railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
      sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
      rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
      rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
      activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
      actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
      rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
      railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
      puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
      puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
      puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
      puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
      puma (3.6.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'

    Started POST "/admin/__better_errors/d8e9adcf6cf62efb/variables" for ::1 at 2017-01-24 23:16:58 -0500
```

This is our dashboard model.

```
class Dashboard < ApplicationRecord

end
```

This is our schema.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170116124600) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "store_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_assignments_on_category_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["store_id"], name: "index_assignments_on_store_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "description"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["post_id"], name: "index_comments_on_post_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_comments_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "follows", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "follower_id"
    t.integer  "followed_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.index ["followed_id"], name: "index_follows_on_followed_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["follower_id", "followed_id"], name: "index_follows_on_follower_id_and_followed_id", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["follower_id"], name: "index_follows_on_follower_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "friend_id"
    t.boolean  "accepted",   default: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
    t.index ["user_id", "friend_id"], name: "index_friendships_on_user_id_and_friend_id", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.string   "image"
    t.integer  "store_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "type"
    t.datetime "start"
    t.datetime "end"
    t.string   "info"
    t.string   "info2"
    t.string   "link"
    t.index ["store_id", "created_at"], name: "index_posts_on_store_id_and_created_at", unique: true, using: :btree
  end

  create_table "reviews", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "review_text"
    t.integer  "rating"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "store_id"
    t.index ["store_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_store_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_reviews_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "searches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "keywords"
    t.string   "category"
    t.integer  "min_price"
    t.integer  "max_price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "stores", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "store_name"
    t.string   "company_name"
    t.string   "image"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "store_link"
    t.integer  "price_rating",       default: 0
    t.string   "contact_number"
    t.string   "contact_number_int"
    t.string   "contact_email"
    t.string   "contact_form_link"
    t.string   "feedback_email"
    t.string   "slogan"
    t.string   "address1"
    t.string   "address2"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "zipcode"
    t.string   "country",            default: "USA"
    t.string   "founded_date"
    t.text     "short_description"
    t.text     "long_description"
    t.string   "facebook_link"
    t.string   "twitter_link"
    t.string   "instagram_link"
    t.string   "google_plus_link"
    t.string   "pinterest_link"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.datetime "created_at",                         null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                         null: false
    t.integer  "reviews_id"
    t.string   "shipping"
    t.index ["reviews_id"], name: "index_stores_on_reviews_id", using: :btree
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "middle_initial"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.date     "birthday"
    t.text     "bio"
    t.string   "occupation"
    t.string   "motto"
    t.string   "website_link"
    t.string   "hometown"
    t.boolean  "is_male",                default: true
    t.integer  "reviews_id"
    t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false
    t.string   "avatar"
    t.integer  "store_id"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
    t.index ["reviews_id"], name: "index_users_on_reviews_id", using: :btree
    t.index ["store_id"], name: "index_users_on_store_id", using: :btree
  end

  add_foreign_key "comments", "posts"
  add_foreign_key "comments", "users"
  add_foreign_key "posts", "stores"
  add_foreign_key "stores", "reviews", column: "reviews_id"
  add_foreign_key "users", "reviews", column: "reviews_id"
end
```

I believe it's the empty model that had to be manually recreated. Is there any way to generate the needed dashboard model and migration for rails_admin again because they were deleted or overwritten? If more information is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It says dashboards table doesn't exist.
Run your migration for dashboards table creation

Comment: I tried that. I've tried bundle install, rake db:reset db:migrate and still this error appears. ERROR:  relation "dashboards" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"dashboards"'::regclass  . I updated my question to better reflect my current rails application status.

Comment: The **dashboards** table does not exist in your schema. Can you post your migration file and the results of the migration run. You can reverse the last migration using ```rake db:rollback STEP=1```

Comment: My last migration was class AddShippingTypeToStores < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :stores, :shipping, :string
  end
end

Comment: I believe it's the empty model that had to be manually recreated. Is there any way to generate the needed dashboard model and migration for rails_admin again because they were deleted or overwritten?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I deleted the manually created dashboard.rb and reinstalled rails_admin. Then I restarted the server and all tests are passing.